# What will happen if an IPv4 packet’s total length field exceeds the packet’s actual length?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

If a router or a host receives a packet, the value of "total length" field is larger than the packet's actual length, what will the router (or the host) do?

Below is a sample, I edited a packet, then captured by Wireshark. But it's only a local capture result, I want to know the actual situation when the packet arrives at a router (or host).

[IPv4 total length exceeds packet length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlzSV.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here since it is not really related to developing code. It should better be asked at [networkengineering.se] or if you are interested in the security aspects of it at [security.se]. In general I would say that it depends on how deep the system is looking at the packet, i.e. a switch will likely just forward it, a router might be forward or drop it, a firewall will hopefully drop it as does an endpoint. It might trigger bugs in systems which are not properly prepared to handle such invalid packets, like embedded systems with small network stacks.

Comment: Indeed it should be fragmented. Some packets are generated without allowing fragmentation and as mentioned by Steffen this well then depend on the upstream device but from my experience this will get dropped.